# Executing a servlet so that my doGet method is called

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm catching a device event, and based on info coming from it it I need to do a login. If the login is verified, I want to move to the next page of my application.

I tried doing it with `HttpURLConnection` but it doesn't actually execute the servlet.

This is the genetic code I'm using:

```
public static String getResponseFromUrl(String url) throws Exception {
    URL website = new URL(url);

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)website.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET"); 
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    connection.setUseCaches(false);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    String response = "";
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        response += inputLine;

    in.close();

    return response.toString();
}
```

I also tried

```
InputStream responseInputStream = connection.getInputStream();
```

but with the same result. The `doGet` method is not being called, and obviously the app doesn't move to the next page.

I'm pretty sure this can be done by catching the event inside the `JSP` page but I was hoping there's an easier solution.

EDIT: When submitting the same URL in the browser it all works. The doGet is called and the app moves to the next page.

Comment: doGet() not called mean doGet() not invoked or getResponseFromUrl() not invoke ? or something else

Comment: getResponseFromUrl() is called and runs with no errors. But the doGet isn't getting called.

Comment: it means into starting when Get-request made at that time doGet() not invoked right ? and if doGet not invoke means all other bla bla not execute. am i correct thinking ?

Comment: The doGet is not invoked, and the response is empty.

Comment: then need to check what error are you phasing ?

Comment: have you ANOTHER servlet which works, called like that ? Have you checks all logs ?

Comment: if you have an empty response, you have a response: then you should see something in logs.

Answer (score -1):

From the Doc :

```
   URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
   HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   try {
     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
     readStream(in);
    finally {
     urlConnection.disconnect();
   }
 }
```

Try with "readStream(in);"

If it still doesn works, the error must be from the URL.
u say u have a doGet method at this url, try with your browser to be sure the URL reponds. Do you really need a different doGet/doPost ? use "service" method instead

Comment: Have u tried this code ? Maybe the doGet method is called but doesnt move to next page